# Discord.py: How do I solve "Command start is already registered" error?

Tags: discord.py

```
@tasks.loop(minutes=1)
async def FunctionTask():
    print("Task running")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    FunctionTask.start()

@client.command()
async def start(ctx):
    FunctionTask.restart()

@client.command()
async def start(ctx):
    FunctionTask.stop()
```

I'm trying to stop and restart a task, but I get errors. What I am doing wrong? Thank you in advance

**edit:** Added error code

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Test.py", line 39, in <module>
    async def start(ctx):
  File "C:\Users\Vortex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1163, in decorator
    self.add_command(result)
  File "C:\Users\Vortex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1071, in add_command
    raise discord.ClientException('Command {0.name} is already registered.'.format(command))
discord.errors.ClientException: Command start is already registered.
```

Comment: What error are you getting?  You're missing the `@` in front of the decorator for `start`

Comment: Thank you, but that is a error while copying here the code, I post the error in the question.

Comment: The error itself explains the problem: `Command start is already registered.`  You can't have 2 commands with the same name: which one would run?

Comment: Thank you I didn't noticed it

Answer (score 0):

you have literally made the start command twice

````
async def start(ctx):
    FunctionTask.restart()

@client.command()
async def start(ctx):
    FunctionTask.stop()```

you might wanna change their names like:
````

@client.command()
async def start(ctx):
FunctionTask.restart()

@client.command()
async def starta(ctx):
FunctionTask.stop()```